# Hierarchy in jersey's EntityHolder type

Tags: java, jaxb, jersey, jax-rs

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "request")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@JSONConfigurable
public class InteractionRequest {
    @XmlElement(name = "skill")
    protected String skillName;
}

@XmlRootElement(name = "request")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@JSONConfigurable
public class InteractionChatRequest extends InteractionRequest {
    @XmlElement
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(LPStringsXmlAdapter.class)
    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "preChatLines")
    protected List<String> line;
}
```

And 2 usages:

```
@PUT
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public Response postExitSurvey(EntityHolder<InteractionRequest> ent) {
    InteractionRequest request = ent.getEntity();
    return null;
}

@POST
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public Response interactionRequest(EntityHolder<InteractionChatRequest> ent) {  
    InteractionChatRequest params = ent.getEntity();
    return null;
}
```

Now, in both cases, the entity holder holds InterationRequest object which results in a ClassCastException in the second usage.

Any idea why? Shouldn't Jersey cast the entity to the type I declare?
Is hierarchy even possible in this case?

Thanks,
Udi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem with the JAXB annotations: both `InteractionRequest` and `InteractionChatRequest` are annotated with `@XmlRootElement(name = "request")`. So they have the same root element, which makes it impossible for JAXB to distinguish between them.

Try to change the `InteractionChatRequest` to `@XmlRootElement(name = "chat-request")`.

Comment: Thanks @Tarlog That worked. This is not a perfect solution, but hey, life ain't perfect ;)

Comment: Just if someone ever gets to this question, I found an even better solution:
I changed the annotation of `InteractionChatRequest` from @XmlRootElement to @XmlType.
Now it works exactly as I wanted...